# Compute $5^{15}$ mod $7$ using the fact that if gcd$(a,n) = 1$, then $a^{\phi(n)}$ mod $n$ = $1$ (Euler-phi function).

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Compute $5^{15}$ mod $7$ using the fact that if gcd$(a,n) = 1$, then $a^{\phi(n)}$ mod $n$ = $1$ (Euler-phi function).

I see that $5^{15} = 5^{6}5^{6}5^{3} = 5^{\phi(n)}5^{\phi(n)}5^{3}$, but I'm not sure if this would help.

Comment: You have already shown that $5^{15}=5^3$ modn.

Comment: I'm assuming there's an interstitial step I'm missing.  All I know is that $5^{15}$ mod $7$ = $5^{\phi(7)}5^{\phi(7)}5^{3}$ mod $7$.

Comment: You didn't completely use the "fact", i.e. you didn't use that $\,5^{\varphi}\equiv 1\,$ to simplify further. Doing so you get $\, 5^{15}\equiv 1\cdot 1\cdot 5^3,\ $ by using standard congruence arithmetic, here the  [congruence produce rule.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already shown $5^{15}=5^{6}\cdot5^{6}\cdot5^{3}=5^{\phi(7)}\cdot5^{\phi(7)}\cdot5^{3}$.

By Euler's theorem, $\gcd(5,7)=1\implies5^{\phi(7)}\equiv1\pmod7$.

Therefore, $5^{\phi(7)}\cdot5^{\phi(7)}\cdot5^{3}\equiv1\cdot1\cdot5^3\equiv125\equiv6\pmod7$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Since $5^6\equiv 1\mod 7$, we have $\;5^{15}\equiv5^{15\bmod 6}=5^3$.

Comment: Hope you don’t mind, but I stuck in the value of $5^6$ for you. I would also recommend using the TeX for congruence (\equiv) rather than the equality sign. But it would’ve been over-editing to do that for you.

Comment: I'd rather thank you – I'm familiar with typos… The equality signs problems come from usually thinking in the quotient ring.